Are there inconsistencies with Anthropic limits?
I have 6 containers that simultaneously interact with the Anthropic API, they send requests approximately every 30 seconds, so I should be well under the 50 requests per minute for the Claude 3.5 Sonnet 2024-10-22 model in Tier 1. Source
However, I get errors that state I only have 5 requests per minute.
Is this a problem with the burst of requests? I am using the computer-use-beta, could this be a problem?

Log the response headers -- both to better inform the question (they include quota details) and to inform yourself. That said, I'm not sure this is a great for the format, being a question where the only people who can answer it definitively are on staff of a proprietary service provider.
